# How to wait for x number of AJAX calls to finish before calling the function for x more times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list = mylist[].

```
 $.each(mylist, function (index, value) {

                myAjaxFunction(index, value)
            });
```

If the list has 50 items, the ajax calls happen in an instant, all 50 of them. And my backend connector timeout before all 50 of the calls are completed.

I want to modify this such that the backend "myAjaxFunction" is called in batches of 5.
So that the function is called 5 times, then it waits for those 5 AJAX calls to finish, before call the function another 5 times, till the end of the list.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=throttle+ajax+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Throttle, debounce, rate limit are the words you are looking for.